# check image format when you know the image path and name

Tags: javascript

Let's say we know the image name and we don't know the format. How we can get the full image source (containing the image format)?

Here is the code I have tried without success:

```js
const pictureFormats = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif"]; // we accept only these picture formats

let notValid = [];

for (let i = 0; i < pictureFormats.length; i++) {
  const format = pictureFormats[i];

  const imageSource = `img/imageName.${format}`;

  try {
    testPictureFormat(imageSource);
  } catch (err) {
    notValid.push(format);
  } finally {
    console.log(notValid);
  }
}

function testPictureFormat(imageSource) {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = imageSource;

  image.onload = function () {
    console.log("There is an image with this url");
  };
}
```

Is there any way? I just get this error:

> Get img/chrome.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Maybe the onerror event is what you're looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to load the image, you might be able to check for its existence with a simple http request:

```js
function fileExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}
```